# How to used Ext.data.Request

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I would like used Ext.data.Request to send request to my server.
But i don't know how to that ?!

I want to push in submit button and it send request to insert data into my database. Insert is manage by an other page !

Thanks to helps :)

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Do you understand what ajax is? Have you tried writing any code? If so, what didn't work?

Comment: yes , i have wrote some code :
`Ext.Ajax.request({
          url: 'test.tcl',
          method : 'POST',
          success: function (){alert('oui');},
          failure: function (){alert('non');},
          
          
         });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean [Ext.Ajax.request](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.Ajax)?  I think [Ext.data.Request](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.data.Request) not that you need.

Code will be look like this:

```
new Ext.Button({
    text: "My button with Ajax",
    handler: function () {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'foo.php',
            success: function (){alert('All good!');},
            failure: function (){alert('Fail...');},
            headers: {
                'my-header': 'foo'
            },
            params: { foo: 'bar' }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer ! 
foo.php page must resend anything in particular ?